# Use properties in gradle liquibase

Tags: gradle, properties, liquibase

I'm trying to run liquibase scripts to create Posgresql DB + schemas.

Here're some pieces of liquibase .groovy configs and scripts and build.gradle.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'liquibase'    
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:1.2.0'
        classpath "org.postgresql:postgresql:${postgreJdbcDriverVersion}"
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/liquibase'
        }
    }
}

liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            File propsFile = new File("src/main/resources/database.properties")
            Properties properties = new Properties()
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
            changeLogFile 'src/main/liquibase/com/freemmy/sample/spring/acl/sample/db/main-changelog.groovy'
            url "${dbUrl}"
            username "${dbUsername}"
            password "${dbPassword}"
        }
    }
    runList = 'main'
}
```

For example I have the following changeset in **main-changelog.groovy**:

```
changeSet(id: '2016-12-10-a', author: 'Dzmitry Dziokin', runInTransaction: false, runAlways: true, runOnChange: true, failOnError: false, dbms: 'postgresql') {
        comment('Create the database role/login')
        // Ok if the role exists
        preConditions(onFail: 'CONTINUE', onFailMessage: 'Role already exists, continue') {
            sqlCheck(expectedResult: '0')
                    { "select count(*) from pg_roles where rolname= '${dbUsername}'" }
        }
        sql(stripComments: true, splitStatements: false, endDelimiter: ';') {
            "CREATE ROLE ${dbUsername} LOGIN PASSWORD '${dbPassword}'"
        }
    }
```

And I have properties `dbUsername` and `dbPassword`.

But when I run, for instance, `gradlew status` I see the following:

```
Execution failed for task ':spring-acl-sample-db:status'.
```

> liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Unexpected error running Liquibase: No such property: dbUsername for class: org.liquibase.groovy.delegate.PreconditionDelegate

I asked Google, but I haven't found any solution or suggestion.

Does someone know what is happening?

Comment: Leaving a comment on this old question for anyone that is trying to write a liquibase preCondition in their groovy file in in a non grails project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the `properties` prefix in the interpolation.

```
url "${properties.dbUrl}"
username "${properties.dbUsername}"
password "${properties.dbPassword}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that dbUsername and dbPassword are defined in your property file.

You'll have to define dbUsername and dbPassword in your gradle script :

```
 def dbUsername = properties.getProperty("dbUsername")
 def dbPassword = properties.getProperty("dbPassword")
```